# How to make Jest run specific test suite named `[Unit] SomeTestSuite` via `--testNamePattern`

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I have a test suite named

```js
describe('[Unit] SomeTestSuite', () => {
// some code here
}
```

I tried running it with

```
npm run mytests -- "--testNamePattern=\[Unit\] SomeTestSuite"
```

and a half dozen of other variants of the regex but nothing worked. I looked through the docs and googled with no luck. It seems square brackets somehow are not escaped. The CLI command just does not find any matching test. The regexes with normal strings work fine though.

Just for informatiion I am under vue-cli and ts-jest, my spec files are TS files if it makes a difference at all.